# Cannot open source file (in PATH)

Tags: c++, cl

I'm trying to run the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator to create dll files for the Bépo keyboard.

In the bin directory is the kbdutool.exe which I'm meant to run at the command line (pictured)

[image: Keyboard Creator folder]

The .c and .h files are generated as a preliminary step before I modify them and compile a dll from these sources. I can't complete the compilation though. The output is:

```
KbdTool v3.40 - convert keyboard text file to C file or a keyboard layout DLL
Compiling layout information from 'bepo.klc' for wow64.
bepo.H : can't open for write.
bepo.C : can't open for write.
bepo.c
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'bepo.c': No such file or directory
CL:EXE returned 2
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
fatal error RC1110: could not open bepo.rc
RC.EXE returned 1
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'bepo.res'
LINK.EXE returned 1181
    2
```

The warnings about not being able to open the files for writing are expected, I was following a guide [here](http://bepo.fr/wiki/Utilisateur:LeBret/Remplacer_AltGr_par_Kana) (in French).

I added this folder to the system path, so I'm not sure what the problem is. If it's of any relevance, cl.exe reports itself to be a 32-bit C/C++ compiler for 80x86. I am using Windows 7 x64. The keyboard tool supports building DLLs for 64-bit targets. It doesn't matter if I change the case of bepo.C to bepo.c, the same problems occur. You can see I moved the folder from its installation location, suspicious that it might have something to do with spaces in the path. I have all aspects of .NET 3.5 enabled.

Comment: You might rename `bepo.C` to `bepo.cc` or `bepo.cpp`

Comment: It still says "no such file or directory" :(

Comment: Did you try running it with ProcMon active to see where it's trying to access something? Also, you don't need .NET at all except for the GUI (`MSKLC.exe`) which is written for .NET 2.0. All other tools are unmanaged native stuff.